# How to change the root system language?

Tags: language

When I first installed elementary, I had the Intel HD5500 glitch and accidentally made my root language Danish. While I managed to change my user language to English, I can't seem to figure out how to get it changed for root uses (when I open Files as administrator for example).

Comment: Sorry, can't check it myself right now, but isn't there an option in the language plug to change "system language" in System Settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your system is up-to-date first (there have been updates related to language settings recently):

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then go to System Settings > Language & Region ([example screenshot](http://lmelinux.net/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2015/08/elementary-0.3.1-language-ui.png)), click on English in the left sidebar and then "Set System Language". You will likely have to enter your password to proceed.

Comment: I have similar problem with language. Could you please take a look?
http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2903/can-not-install-japanese-language