# Can not install Japanese language

Tags: settings, language

I'm trying to install Japanese language using last Freya release.
Steps:

1) Hit **+** in **Language&Region** settings.
2) Find *japanese* or 日本語.
3) Double-click
4) Then the left bar becomes greyed out and not responsive. Can not see any visible progress.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Nothing wrong* in your steps, it happens to me as well, *might* be a bug.

But we need to install

> language-pack-gnome-ja
>   language-pack-gnome-ja-base
>   language-pack-ja
>   language-pack-ja-base

While installing from terminal using `apt-get` getting dependency errors as in the bug.(*I missed the bug page, I will add the link later*)

I manually installed all the `.deb` packages,

First download all `.deb` files,

[language-pack-ja](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/214456012/language-pack-ja_14.04%2B20150804_all.deb)

[language-pack-ja-base](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/214456132/language-pack-ja-base_14.04%2B20150804_all.deb)

[language-pack-gnome-ja-base](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/172559423/language-pack-gnome-ja-base_14.04%2B20140410_all.deb)

[language-pack-gnome-ja](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/214456150/language-pack-gnome-ja_14.04%2B20150804_all.deb)

Now install in the order either from Software Centre or from terminal,

From terminal (I suggest use terminal, If you got errors use Software center)

```
cd ~/Downloads
ls #to avoid errors with file names
sudo dpkg -i [language-pack-ja deb]
sudo dpkg -i [language-pack-ja-base deb]
sudo dpkg -i [language-pack-gnome-ja-base deb]
sudo dpkg -i [language-pack-gnome-ja deb]
sudo apt-get update
```

[image: Imgur]

**EDIT**:

If still not able to change to *japanese*, Again follow the procedure,

1) Hit **+** in *Language&Region* settings.
2) Find japanese or 日本語.
3) Double-click (This time should work, as shown in screenshot)

[image: Imgur]

After that hit <kbd>set language</kbd> and <kbd>set system language</kbd>

You need to `restart` system to apply changes.

After restart, your language settings will be changed,

[image: Imgur]

[image: Imgur]

Comment: Cool thanks! Gonna check it. Be right back!

Comment: please follow the order to avoid dependency issue =) @orkenstein

Comment: please see my __edit__ @orkenstein

Comment: No success. When I'm doing `sudo dpkg -i language-pack-ja_14.04+20150804_all.deb`  get: `dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of language-pack-ja:
 language-pack-ja depends on language-pack-ja-base (>= 1:14.04+20150804); however:
  Package language-pack-ja-base is not configured yet.`
But `sudo dpkg -i language-pack-ja-base_14.04+20150804_all.deb` I get:
`dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of language-pack-ja-base:
 language-pack-ja-base depends on language-pack-ja (>= 1:14.04+20150804); however:
  Package language-pack-ja is not configured yet.
`
This is strange.

Comment: After some puzzling with packages I finally installed all the dependencies. Change link `language-pack-gnome-ja-base_14.04%2B20140410_all.deb` -> `20150804`
Is it ok that some text is still in English? For example *Desktop, Notifications, Language&Region* in *System Settings*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31400/discussion-between-ravan-and-orkenstein).