# Russian language not installing

Tags: language

There is a HUUGE problem with translations.
1-st... rus. language not installed completly. After trying to complete installation... all the system get english.
Even if I remoove the engllish, it's still exist.

Comment: related: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2903/can-not-install-japanese-language/2905#2905